# Group by Category in Outlook 2013/2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-outlook-2016

A customer approached me here at the IT desk wondering if it is possible to group by **multiple** categories in Outlook. The existing "group by" category feature creates individual drop-downs for each category, but what is desired is the ability to show only a select few as well as uncategorized.

Example categories that they want to show would be the name of the person handling the email (this is a shared inbox), and then ignore the other categories they use such as locations.

I'm reaching out to the community here to see if anyone knows any options or third-party tools that can do such a thing. I attempted to use *KuTools* but that did not have what I needed.

Hopefully I explained this well enough as it is a rather confusing. Please let me know if I can help clarify.

Comment: You want to tag e-mails?

Answer (score 0):

Categories are mailbox or account specific. Best you can probably do is sort the Categories by alpha. If you add a prefix (e.g. a special character ~), you group the Categories together. Remember Categories work like Tags and only the text is transferred between accounts. The color coding is specific to each workstation.